# In WooCommerce, can I add a checkbox for adding related products to the purchase?

Tags: ecommerce, plugin, shopping-cart, shopping, woocommerce

Using WooCommerce, I am selling a few different items, one of the items is a polishing cloth for $3.00 and different pairs of earrings. If someone goes to buy a pair of earrings I want to have a check box to allow the user to simultaneously add a polishing cloth for a discounted price of $2.00 if they choose. Any ideas on how to do this?

Does WooCommerce already have this functionality and I just can't find it?
If not, is there a plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions for how to setup up related products, up-sells, and cross-sells:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/

However, if you want to allow a related product to have a discount when bundled, you'll need this plugin: http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/